# Python zip behavior with dictionary

Tags: python

Just starting to learn Python and noticed the following behavior when using zip with dictionaries.

`print(list(zip({4,5,6}, {7,8,9})))`

returns:
`[(4, 8), (5, 9), (6, 7)]`

instead of the expected:
`[(4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9)]`

Why is this ordering the values in the second dictionary differently than input?

Comment: I don't see any dictionaries here, though.

Comment: Those are not dictionaries. They are sets. Sets are not ordered (neither are dictionaries, btw), so the order is undefined.